Integrated terminal not working properly during debugging in VS Code
I am currently trying to debug a C program in Visual Studio Code using gdb (on Windows) but when I start it in the integrated terminal, the text becomes unreadable after a few lines of code had been executed. Some goes to the right side of the terminal, other doesn't even print. However, when I set "externalConsole" to true and use that instead, everything works. The thing is that using the external console is not quite convenient for me. So far I have tried restarting VS Code and setting "externalConsole" to true. Any ideas on how to fix this?
Here is the launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:/Users/plame/projects/projects/SMS.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

